# ¿Cómo obtener el promedio de un array con un bucle "for in"?

Tags: javascript, array

el ejercicio que me piden, es que realice el **promedio de un array** pero debe ser utilizando el bucle "**for in**" de forma obligatoria.
Mi problema es que cuando coloco `suma =+ item` me retorna el un resultado concatenado y no sumado ejemplo `05` en vez de `5`

```js
var myArray = [5,23,5656,423];

for (var index in myArray){
  
  //tu codigo aquí
  let suma = 0
  suma+= index;
  // hasta aquí
  
 console.log(myArray[index]);
 
}
```

Comment: Eso es raro, porque estás sumando los índices... ¿Viste el resultado de tu `console.log()`? Ahí tienes la pista para saber qué hacer. Otra cosa, debes definir `suma` fuera del ciclo, porque en cada iteración se sobreescribe.

Answer (score 1):

Cosas a mencionar:

- Como ya te mencionaron declara a `suma` duera del contexto del ciclo, ya que de lo contrario por cada iteración la variable se *declara nuevamente*
- Posterior en la variable acumuladora que es `suma` asignale la suma del valor que en cada iteración recuperas del *myArray* y que esta contenido en la variable *index*
- Imprime por fuera el valor de suma, para que de esta forma obtengas el acumulado y evitemos lo del primer punto mencionado
- Para completar el proceso del promedio, divide a suma entre la longitud del vector original, accediendo a la propiedad `.length`

**Ejemplo**

```js
    let myArray = [5,23,5656,423];
    
    let suma = 0
    
    for(let index in myArray) {
      suma += myArray[index]
    
    }
    
      console.log(suma/myArray.length)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no entendía porque debía declarar la variable fuera, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta